# Updating an array element in Mongoose by ID

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to modify an array element in a single MongoDB document, but I can't figure out how. Here is an example document I have.

```
{
    "_id": "5eefbb77dcc4af0255ef52c6",
    "question": "How are you?",
    "answers": [
      {
        "count": 5,
        "_id": "5eefbb77dcc4af0255ef52c7",
        "body": "Fantastic"
      },
      {
        "count": 20, // I want to increment this by 1
        "_id": "5eefbb77dcc4af0255ef52c8",
        "body": "Meh"
      },
      {
        "count": 100,
        "_id": "5eefbb77dcc4af0255ef52c9",
        "body": "Bad"
      }
    ],
    "createdAt": "2020-06-21T19:56:39.336Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-06-21T19:56:39.336Z",
    "__v": 0
  },
```

I'm currently trying to use document.FindByIdAndUpdate(), but I can't figure out how. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This should work just fine for you:

```
    Model.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: "5eefbb77dcc4af0255ef52c6", "answers._id": "5eefbb77dcc4af0255ef52c8" }, 
     { $inc: { "answers.$.count": 1 }, 
     { new: true } 
    })
    .then((item) => {
       console.log(item)
    }, (e) => {
       console.log(e)
    })
```

The query above will find the exact answer and then increment the count by 1.